# Hardness of approximately counting independent sets with a PRAS, rather than FPRAS

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-algorithms, counting-complexity, approximation-hardness

It is known that approximately counting the independent sets of a graph is hard, even if randomness can be used, and even if we restrict ourselves to bounded degree graphs with degree bound at least 6. Specifically, if an FPRAS exists for such a graph class, it is known to imply the unlikely collapse $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{RP}$.

My question is: what happens if we are satisfied with a PRAS, rather than FPRAS? That is, in the same setting, we only require that the algorithm runs in polynomial time for any *fixed* error parameter $\epsilon>0$, but does not have to be polynomially bounded in $1/\epsilon$. Is there any hardness result known with this weaker assumption?

Comment: It is relatively easy to argue via amplification that if you have a poly(n)-factor polynomial-time approximation for these counting problems then you can get all the way to a FPRAS. Thus, having a PTAS would imply FPRAS because PTAS already implies a constant factor approximation.